# Define a new console.log and desactivate the orginal one

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, logging, internet-explorer-9

I would like to create a variable which do exactly the same as console.log and deactivate the original console.log.

```
newLog('hello world'); // Should be displayed
console.log('hello world'); // Should be ignored
```

I found two ways:

First one:

```
var newLog = console.log;
console.log = function() {};
```

Second:

```
var newLog = console.log.bind(console);
console.log = function() {};
```

The first one works with IE9 but not with Chrome.
The second one works with Chrome but not with IE9.
I didn't try on other browsers.

Is there a way to get all browser working together without mixing solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `window.navigator` object to figure out what the browser currently is, and combine it with an if else statement

```
if(isChrome) {
   //execute chrome specific code
} else if(isIE) {
   //execute IE code
}
```